# Passing a query parameter to the Go HTTP request handler using the MUX package

Tags: http, authentication, go, mux

I am trying to pass an additional parameter in the request I am trying to send to the Go server -

```
websocket.create_connection("ws://<ip>:port/x/y?token="qwerty")
```

The Go server implementation is as follows -

```
func main() {
    err := config.Parse()
    if err != nil {
        glog.Error(err)
        os.Exit(1)
        return
    }

    flag.Parse()
    defer glog.Flush()

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    http.Handle("/", httpInterceptor(router))

    router.Handle("/v1/x", common.ErrorHandler(stats.GetS)).Methods("GET")
    router.Handle("/v1/x/y", common.ErrorHandler(stats.GetS)).Methods("GET")

    var listen = fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", config.Config.Ip, config.Config.Port)
    err = http.ListenAndServe(listen, nil)

    if err != nil {
        glog.Error(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

func httpInterceptor(router http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        startTime := time.Now()

        if !auth.Auth(w, req) {
            http.Error(w, "Failed authentication", 401)
            return
        }

        router.ServeHTTP(w, req)

        finishTime := time.Now()
        elapsedTime := finishTime.Sub(startTime)

        switch req.Method {
        case "GET":
        case "POST":
        }

    })
}
```

How should I look and parse for the token in the Go server so that the authentication is successful?

Library function

```
func ParseFromRequest(req *http.Request, keyFunc Keyfunc) (token *Token, err error) {

    // Look for an Authorization header
    if ah := req.Header.Get("Authorization"); ah != "" {
        // Should be a bearer token
        if len(ah) > 6 && strings.ToUpper(ah[0:6]) == "BEARER" {
            return Parse(ah[7:], keyFunc)
        }
    }

    // Look for "access_token" parameter
    req.ParseMultipartForm(10e6)
    if tokStr := req.Form.Get("access_token"); tokStr != "" {
        return Parse(tokStr, keyFunc)
    }

    return nil, ErrNoTokenInRequest

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Call [FormValue](http://godoc.org/net/http#Request.FormValue) to get a query parameter:

```
token := req.FormValue("token")
```

`req` is a the `*http.Request`

An alternative is to call [ParseForm](http://godoc.org/net/http#Request.ParseForm) and access `req.Form` directly:

```
if err := req.ParseForm(); err != nil {
   // handle error
}
token := req.Form.Get("token")
```

The OP asks in a comment how to map `"token"` to `"access_token"` for an external package that's looking `"access_token"`. Execute this code before calling the external package:

```
if err := req.ParseForm(); err != nil {
   // handle error
}
req.Form["access_token"] = req.Form["token"]
```

When the external package calls `req.Form.Get("access_token")`, it will get the same value as the `"token"` parameter.

Comment: How about i use something like this -
token := req.URL.Query().Get("token")

Comment: Cool, thanks , How do i pass in this token parameter to the Auth function being used in the code above ? 

 Another question is have that the external library i am using looks for "access_token" parameter and in my server code, i would add this logic to handle "token" parameter. How can i internally map "token" to "Access_token" so that the library can successfully authenticate this token being passed in the request?

Comment: This is the Auth function 
token, err := jwt.ParseFromRequest(req, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
  return config.Config.Key, nil
 })

Comment: The library has the implementation of ParseFromRequest which looks like this - 

func ParseFromRequest(req *http.Request, keyFunc Keyfunc) (token *Token, err error) {

 // Look for an Authorization header
 if ah := req.Header.Get("Authorization"); ah != "" {
  // Should be a bearer token
  if len(ah) > 6 && strings.ToUpper(ah[0:6]) == "BEARER" {
   return Parse(ah[7:], keyFunc)
  }
 }

 // Look for "access_token" parameter
 req.ParseMultipartForm(10e6)
 if tokStr := req.Form.Get("access_token"); tokStr != "" {
  return Parse(tokStr, keyFunc)
 }

 return nil, ErrNoTokenInRequest

}

Comment: Pasted the above function in the description on the top.

Comment: I see, thanks 3of3 , I will let you know if this worked for me. I am interested in authenticating this request as you would have seen by passing the token.

Comment: Is there a way that I use req.URL.Query().Get("token") to fetch the token and be able to assign it to req.Form("access_token") ?

Answer (score 5):

Depending on the way you want to parse the token , if its coming from the form or the URL.

The first answer can be used if the token is being sent from the form while in case of a URL, I would suggest using this. This works for me

```
token := req.URL.Query().Get("token")
```

Answer (score 0):

For url query parameters:

```
mux.Vars(r)["token"]
```